# WebView loading error

Tags: java, android, webview

My webview is not loading a html string like:

```
wv.loadData(htmlstring, "text/html", "UTF-8")

wv.loadData(htmlstring, "text/html; charset="utf8", null)
```

Im getting an error:

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2475)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:547FD97F]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : BackFramebuffer::Create: <- error from previous GL command
```

Js is enabled. What could be the reason? I guess it is a memory problem, coz my wv is in `ScrollView` (and yes, i REALLY need that).

Comment: There isnt enough to go off here read this [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: but there is no more to say. I have an html string with links, images etc. WebView not loading it at all, just empty. I guess its due to webview was resized to full length inside scroll view. May be someone was faced the same trouble.